# Regular posts first (descending order), then custom post type (alphabetical) in WP search

Tags: wordpress, search, grouping, custom-post-type, alphabetical-sort

I've been cobbling together bits and pieces of various examples together but can't seem to wrap my head around this.

I have regular blog posts (News) that I would like displayed with the most recent on top followed by a custom post type (Businesses) that I would like grouped below the News. I am using Sage and this is my first theme.

Here is my beginner code so far:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header'); ?>

    <?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <?php _e('Sorry, no results were found.', 'sage'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() ); ?>
                            <?php $type = get_post_type(); ?>

                                <?php if ($type == 'post') { ?>
                                    <h2>News Results</h2>
                                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <?php $cats=get_the_category(); ?>
                                                    <?php echo $cats[0]->cat_name; ?>

                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                                            <div class="result-excerpt">
                                                <?php if ( has_excerpt( $post->ID ) ) {
              echo the_excerpt(); 
            } else {
              echo get_excerpt(); 
            } ?>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </article>

                                    <?php } elseif ($type == 'business') { ?>

                                        <h2>Business Results</h2>
                                        <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                            <header>
                                                <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                <?php if (get_post_type() === 'post') { get_template_part('templates/entry-meta'); } ?>
                                            </header>
                                            <div class="entry-summary">
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <?php $cats=get_the_category(); ?>
                                                    <?php echo $cats[0]->cat_name; ?> -
                                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                            </a>
                                            <h3><?php echo the_sub_field('title'); ?></h3>
                                            <?php if( get_sub_field('content') ): ?>
                                                <div class="result-excerpt">
                                                    <?php echo custom_field_excerpt(); ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                        </article>

                                        <?php } ?>

                                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So you've created a specific custom post type for Business articles and not used categories?

Comment: Asking for clarification so I can tailor the proposed fix for you.

Comment: The CPT business has both categories and tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're looping over every post, in order, and deciding what to do with it. This will result in the output, whatever it is, in the same order as the input.

I don't speak very fluent PHP, but I think what's happening is that the algorithm reads like this:

```
-for each post:
  - if it's a 'post', display it like «this»
  - otherwise, if it's a 'business', display it instead like «this»
```

I think you want to have two loops, like this:

```
-for each post:
  - if it's a 'post', display it like «this»
-for each post:
  - if it's a 'business', display it like «this»
```

Unfortunately, I don't see an obvious reference to store in an array and loop over. I really don't know how sage works, so I'll have to leave the implementation to you. My best guess - and I sincerely doubt this will work - is as follows:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header'); ?>

<?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        <?php _e('Sorry, no results were found.', 'sage'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() ); ?>
                        <?php $type = get_post_type(); ?>

                            <?php if ($type == 'post') { ?>
                                <h2>News Results</h2>
                                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                    <div>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                            <?php $cats=get_the_category(); ?>
                                                <?php echo $cats[0]->cat_name; ?>

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                                        <div class="result-excerpt">
                                            <?php if ( has_excerpt( $post->ID ) ) {
          echo the_excerpt(); 
        } else {
          echo get_excerpt(); 
        } ?>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </article>

                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>







        <?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <?php _e('Sorry, no results were found.', 'sage'); ?>
            </div>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() ); ?>
                                <?php $type = get_post_type(); ?>

                                    <?php if ($type == 'business') { ?>

                                            <h2>Business Results</h2>
                                            <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
                                                <header>
                                                    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                    <?php if (get_post_type() === 'post') { get_template_part('templates/entry-meta'); } ?>
                                                </header>
                                                <div class="entry-summary">
                                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                </div>
                                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                    <?php $cats=get_the_category(); ?>
                                                        <?php echo $cats[0]->cat_name; ?> -
                                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                                </a>
                                                <h3><?php echo the_sub_field('title'); ?></h3>
                                                <?php if( get_sub_field('content') ): ?>
                                                    <div class="result-excerpt">
                                                        <?php echo custom_field_excerpt(); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                            </article>

                                            <?php } ?>

                                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Good luck!